# VS Code Remote SSH failing to find IdentityFile with Windows Git Bash path

Tags: bash, git, ssh

VS Code is prompting for a password every time to connect to my server using Remote Explorer, even though I have an SSH key set up and it works in Git Bash. When I click try connecting I get the popup saying `Setting up SSH Host mywebsite.com: (details) Initializing VS Code Server` and when I click details I see `no such identity: /c/Users/Adam/.ssh/id_rsa_root_mywebsite.com: No such file or directory`.

This file does exist but I'm assuming it's failing to find it because this is a Git Bash file path and it's trying to run the command in cmd or PowerShell. But I have my default terminal set to Git Bash.

`settings.json`

```
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash",
```

`C:\Users\Adam\.ssh\config`

```
Host mywebsite.com
  HostName mywebsite.com
  User root
  IdentityFile /c/Users/Adam/.ssh/id_rsa_root_mywebsite.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though Git Bash is the default terminal, the Remote SSH feature directly invokes ssh commands using whatever ssh command it finds in PATH. The solution was to add this line to `settings.json`:

```
"remote.SSH.path": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin\\ssh.exe",
```